Using thermal conductivity to approximate cooling time
I was just looking at some problems in an engineering class curriculum and there's a unit on material properties, one of which is thermal conductivity coefficient $k$, given in tables in the units of W/(m·K).
I was thinking about using that to approximate the time it takes for a cup of $80°\text{C}$ coffee to reach equilibrium with a room at $20°\text{C}$.
The formula given for $Q'$ (rate of energy transfer in watts) is
$$Q' = \frac{k A \Delta T}{L}. \tag1 $$
So I tried to model a coffee cup, using
$$k = 3.8\,\text{W}\text{m}^{-1}\text{K}^{-1}, \ \Delta T = 60\,\text{K}, \ A = 0.0234 \,\text{m}^2, L = 0.005\,\text{m}.$$
I assumed a cup $h=9\,\text{cm}$ tall and $p=26\,\text{cm}$ around, with the lateral area $A = h p = 0.0234\,\text{m}^2$ and a wall thickness $L=0.005\,\text{m}$.
So when I plugged in the numbers, I got
$$Q' = \frac{(3.8\,\text{W}\text{m}^{-1} \text{K}^{-1})(0.0234\,\text{m}^2)(60\,\text{K})}{0.005\,\text{m}}= \frac{5.335}{0.005}=5076\,\text{W}, \tag2$$
which seems rather a lot for a coffee cup full of $80°\text{C}$ coffee.
In any case, this tells me the rate of heat transfer. So how long would it take that volume of water to cool off? We can find the total heat of cooling or heating of $m\,\text{kg}$ of water knowing its specific heat $c=4181\,\text{J}/(\text{kg}\cdot \text{K})$ using
$$Q=mc \Delta T$$
and when I use that I get
$$Q = mc \Delta T = 0.480\,\text{kg}\cdot 4181\,\text{J}/(\text{kg}\cdot \text{K}) \cdot 60\,\text{K} = 24082560\,\text{J}. \tag3$$
So I know my rate of heat transfer $Q'= 5076\,\text{W}$. The total the coffee dissipates as it cools down from $80°\text{C}$ to $20°\text{C}$ is $Q = 2408256\,\text{J}$.
Dividing (3) by (2), we obtain the equilibration time:
$$\frac{Q}{Q'} = \frac{2408256\,\text{J}}{5076\,\text{W}}=4744.4\,\text{s}.$$
That's about 1 hour 20 min, and in my experience it takes hot coffee at least that long to cool completely.
This is a first approximation, of course, I was curious if the method I used in this was in any way really suspect or unsound.

One of my profs of my undergrad years was an amazingly nice man. He salvaged our homework if physical thinking was right, the result not of an insane magnitude of error, and the mistakes were in calculations only. This was before Mathematica, Excel or even PCs; calculators had already existed tho. But he graded an exercise at 0 points for calculation like 3.141×2.718=8.537238. You are not allowed to conjure significant digits out of thin air. 0.480kg×4181J/kg×60º=24×10⁶J. 0.480×4181×60.0=24.1×10⁶. 0.480×4181×60.000=24.1×10⁶ also. You have the lowest 3 decimals in 0.480, thus 3 in the answer.

BTW, if that's not a homework exercise that was assigned to you, but rather tinkering with the engineering approximation formulas and your own problem statement, then remove the 'homework-and-exercises' tag. Homework-tagged answers are presented very differently: you're only given minor hints. But your own problem is open to the full deep analysis. I'll hold my answering the question, as your text suggests this is not an assigned homework (“I was thinking about using that to approximate the time it takes for a cup …” etc.).

Jesse, @ me in a comment when you're decided about the homework status of your question, lest I forget. Your question is very interesting to answer from the angle of the difference between engineering and physics approaches: the engineer opens a book with the algorithm to calculate a quantity, but the physicist understands what's really going on, and whether a formula looks suspicious or fine.

@kkmmistrustsSE think I added the Homework tag accidentally... I ws thinking more in terms of lesson design. anyhow I teach an engineering curriculum to 9th graders and was tinkering with this stuff to see if it made sense because it's one of the engineering / physics type areas that doesn't require a ton of calculus or trig.

@kkmmistrustsSE also I am aware of the significant digits issue, but in this case that wasn't the focus of what I was doing. I was rounding off to what was convenient for the calculation. (I tell my students to NOT use all the digits a calculator gives you, just a couple past the decimal are fine in most cases).

so @kkmmistrustsSE  trying to get this to work

@kkm mistrusts SE -- see if this works too

You have nearly recapitulated the lumped-component method of thermal analysis. However, your 9th graders may very well have some reasonable objections or questions:

Most problematically, you assume a constant outward heat flux that's calculated based on the initial temperature difference. But of course the coffee is cooling over time, and the cooling time is the central result you're trying to achieve. The lumped component analysis addresses this by making the temperature change rate $\frac{dT(t)}{dt}$ rely on the current temperature $T(t)$, not the initial temperature, which results in a differential equation whose solution is an exponentially asymptotic approach to room temperature. If you wish to avoid this level of math, you could simply look at the rate of coffee cooling in the first minute, for example, during which the temperature doesn't change much.

You assume that the outside surface of the mug is at room temperature. This is easily experimentally disproven; cups of hot coffee tend to feel hot, often uncomfortably hot. You could address this issue in a number of ways. One is to use the composite thermal resistance of conduction through the cup material plus convection from the cup to the air. Another is to assume a cup material that's so thermally nonconductive (e.g., styrofoam) that the outside surface is indeed nearly at room temperature. Make sure to update the thermal conductivity and thickness appropriately.

You implicitly assume that the cooling coffee is always a single uniform temperature, or equivalently that the Biot number is far less than 1. You could explore this aspect by calculating the Biot number with the students, or assume that the coffee is being stirred, for instance, or simply assume a uniform temperature for simplicity. This isn't really a problem with your analysis, as the Biot number is probably going to be small, and cooling coffee in this context is reasonably close to a uniform temperature; it's just one aspect of the model that might arise in discussion.

You ignore evaporation, which could have a substantial cooling effect. You could consider a closed cup, or simply say that this aspect is ignored for simplicity.

Perceptive or simply argumentative students might ask whether the material properties vary with temperature. They do, but that issue is likely outside the scope of this lesson. This question could be a sign of a good future engineer/researcher or a malcontent or both; there's some overlap.



Thanks this helps a lot; honestly none of my students has raised the problems you raise; I have mentioned to them that in reality cooling isn't perfect and cooling isn't constant either (Newton's cooling law is a differential as I recall). I understand many of the things I am not taking into account here; I was trying to come up with an analysis that I could do with kids who have algebra at most, just to show that you can calculate it using these formulas ("what is it for" is among the most common questions a teacher hears)

It’s a great heat transfer exercise; arguably, the only thing that’s really flat wrong at this level is assuming the cup loses energy based on the initial 60°C temperature difference even when it’s at 30°C. As noted, this can be addressed by considering only the early rate of cooling. Alternatively, the time you calculate could serve as an estimate for the minimum cooling time, as the cup will never cool faster than when it’s at its hottest.

precisely that; I told the kids it was an absolute minimum and that usually the times would be a lot longer because we don't live in a world of perfect conduction, energy transfer, et cetera.

Along with your beam deflection solution on Engineering Stack Exchange (no complaints there), they’re getting great exposure to more-or-less the standard second-year engineering curriculum.
